# Oxidation of Unsymmetrical Ketones using Selenium Dioxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

I have searched the whole internet but I could only see examples where the authors of the article took $\ce{R1}$ and $\ce{R2}$ as the alkyl groups around the carbon.
 This is regarding the oxidation of carbonyl compounds (I am specifically searching about ketones) using $\ce{SeO2}$. 
What I understood was $\ce{C=O}$ got introduced on the alpha-carbon and two hydrogens from that carbon were lost. 
I would like to know the product obtained on reacting pentan-2-one with $\ce{SeO2}$. Will the carbon having 3 alpha-hydrogens become $\ce{C=O}$ or will the other one having 2 alpha hydrogens become $\ce{C=O}$?

**References**:

1. Selenium dioxide oxidation of ketones and aldehydes. Evidence for
   the intermediacy of .beta.-ketoseleninic, K. Barry Sharpless and
   Kenneth M. Gordon Journal of the American Chemical Society,
   **1976**, 98 (1), 300-301 DOI: [10.1021/ja00417a083](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja00417a083)
2. https://www.adichemistry.com/organic/organicreagents/seo2/selenium-dioxide-seo2.html

Comment: See Riley Oxidation

Comment: You find some insight [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33034/why-doesnt-the-seo2-oxidation-of-ketones-stop-at-the-hydroxyketone-stage).

Answer (score 3):

The mechanism of Selenium Dioxide (Riley) oxidation proceeds *via* the enol tautomer of the ketone (see scheme - image from Wikipedia). If the ketone is assymetric and can enolise to either side then the reaction should give the two di-ketones in proportion to the amount of either enol formed though I cannot find any reference where this has been experimentally demonstrated. In the OP's case of 2-pentanone, a mixture of the two possible products will be formed.

[image]

Comment: why would it not make a double bond as  it does for 1,4 diketones?

Comment: @https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33034/why-doesnt-the-seo2-oxidation-of-ketones-stop-at-the-hydroxyketone-stage: It's depend on the several factors including structure of starting material, solvent, and pH. You can find an answer to your question [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33034/why-doesnt-the-seo2-oxidation-of-ketones-stop-at-the-hydroxyketone-stage).